# haskell redirect

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming

Working in F# has lead me to learn about Haskell. I'm currently on chapter 7 of [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) tutorial which I HIGHLY recommend.
Quick question though. Maybe I'm getting ahead of myself and I'll find the answer in future chapters but, is there a way to reverse the position of the function and it's arguments if the function only takes one argument like in F#.
So, for example, in F# if you had a function called digitToInt (as you do in Haskell), you could do the following:

3 |> digitToInt

I know about using back ticks, but that's specifically for binary functions. Is there anything similar for unary functions?

Comment: There is no left-to-right application operator in the standard libraries.  However, `Control.Arrow` defines `(>>>)` which can behave as left-to-right _composition_.  Other than that, see peoro's answer.  The convention in Haskell culture is to have data flow top-to-bottom, right-to-left, so it's probably best if you just get used to that way.

Comment: cool. just curious but that's informative. thanks.

Comment: Note that |> is widely used in F# code because of F#'s "left to right" type inference (so sometimes you need to either use |> or explicitly specify the type in your code for it to compile). This is not the case for Haskell, so (.) and ($) is all you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do that could be defining an infix function `(|>)` that take a value and a function and calls the function passing it the value like this:

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) x f = f x
```

Then you can use it exactly like in your example:

```
3 |> digitToInt
```

Comment: In other words, `(|>) = flip ($)`

Comment: yes. Once I put my question into words, I wondered if flip could play into it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do what peoro suggests and it works fine. However, I'd advise against it. The normal way to "read" Haskell is like a sentence -- left to right, with verbs at the beginning and the subject at the end. Typically you get a chained composition like `f . g. q . r $ x`. With monadic operators you get `f =<< g =<< x` (or `(f <=< g) =<< x`) and with applicatives you get `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`. So reversing the normal order of things is not necessarily idiomatic.

By the way, the reason, so I've heard, that F# chose the opposite operator is that it works very very nicely with visualstudio autocomplete -- if you've typed in the value you're operating on, then its type can determine choices for what can operate on it. That sort of tooling support is awesome, and it would be a good argument for adopting an alternate style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Haskell has a standard operator for this (I may be wrong), but you can certainly define one. A somewhat related concept is the `$` operator that allows you to get rid of parentheses when writing a series of applications (which is one reason for using `|>` in F#). The difference is that `$` doesn't reverse the order:

```
f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))
```

BTW: A fantastic way to find out things like this in Haskell is to use Hoogle. For example:

- http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+b